# Export to Excel - with expanded column data in php

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I want to save exported excelsheet with expanded column width to the length of data.

my code

```
 //pdo 
 $ret->execute($whr_val);
 $count = $ret->columnCount();
 $out = $ret->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $fields = array_keys($out[0]);



    HEADER("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_dump.xls");
    HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
    HEADER("Expires: 0");
    if($Use_Title == 1)
         echo "$title\n";
    $sep = "\t"; //line seperator
    //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
    foreach ($fields as $f)
        echo $f. "\t";
    print("\n");
    //end of printing column names
    //start while loop to get data
    foreach($out as $row)
    { 
        //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<$count; $j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$fields[$j]]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$fields[$j]] != "")
                $schema_insert .= $row[$fields[$j]].$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        //in excel \n or \r characters are now replaced with a space 
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }
```

For example I have column `mobile number` which is showing like `7.4E+09`. If I expand column, it showing full number as "7418724187".

when opening the exported excel file, I want to show the "7418724187" not as `7.4E+09`

Comment: When you use a CSV format, then MS Excel will modify numeric values to show them as numbers.... unless you want to go to the effort of creating a genuine BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format Excel file, then try wrapping these values in quotes (`"012345"`) or prefixing the quoted value with `=`  (`=""012345""`)

Comment: @MarkBaker For text value also it showed only 8 characters length. I want to show full text. atleast upto 20 characters

Comment: MS Excel has a default width for columns, that applies if you load from something like a CSV file.... CSV is limiting

Comment: If you need to be able to set column widths, then you need to use a file format that supports column width settings when imported into MS Excel, such as native BIFF or OfficeOpenXML formats

Answer (score 1):

Because phone numbers can contain special characters and leading zero's it's usually better to store them as text. Excel is now interpreting your data as number, which is the reason for the notation that you are observing. You need to force the value as a string value. (you could try adding quotes, which helped a couple of times in my case)

Comment: For text value also it showed only 8 characters length. I want to show full text. atleast upto 20 characters.     for ex: show **office sp** instead of **office space**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use any php excel export library. Inbuilt libraries have data-type options so these types of issues can be resolved. Library example :

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel